# Issue with nested if-else loops

Tags: r, if-statement, mutate

I am very much at the very beginning of coding in R and I have been trying to expand on a simple if_else function that I had before by adding a new condition, but for some reason it is not working.

What I had before:

```
data2 <- data1 %>%
mutate (score = if_else (lev <= 1, 1, 0))
```

This was working as intended - it was creating a "score" column based on the values in the "lev" column - if they were lower or equal than 1, it would assign 1, otherwise it would be 0.

What I tried to do next was to expand this by adding a new condition where the scoring would depend on another column ("Wordclass"):

```
if (data2$Wordclass=="Preposition" || data2$Wordclass=="Noun") {
mutate (data2$score2 = if_else (data2$lev <= 1, 1, 0))
} else {
mutate (data2$score2 = if_else (data2$lev <= 3, 1, 0))
}
```

What I tried to achieve with this code: if Wordclass would be a preposition or a noun then the same scoring condition as before would apply (lev<=1), but if the wordclass would be anything else, then the scoring condition would be different (lev<=3).
However, I am getting the following error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "if (data2$Wordclass=="Preposition" ||
> data2$Wordclass=="Noun") {mutate (data2$score ="

I have tried different combinations and options and looking for an answer online, but was unable to find the solution. I am pretty new to this so I am aware it might be a very obvious mistake. If anyone could identify it and offer a solution, I would appreciate it!

Comment: 1) When posting a question it is helpful to include either dummy data or a sample of your data set. You can use `dput(data1)` to share code to reproduce your dataset. 2) Without the dataset it's hard to test, but the positional arguments for `mutate` are the data set, then the mutating commands. Try something like `mutate(data2, score2 = if_else...` in both instances

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that might help you:

#### Data

```
data <-
  data.frame(
    Wordclass = c("Preposition","Noun","Preposition","Noun","Other","Other"),
    lev = c(0,1,1,0,2,5)
  )
```

#### Code

library(dplyr)

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    score2 =  case_when(
      (Wordclass== "Preposition" | Wordclass=="Noun") ~ if_else(lev <= 1, 1, 0),
      TRUE ~ if_else(lev <= 3, 1, 0)
    )
  )
```

#### Output

```
    Wordclass lev score2
1 Preposition   0      1
2        Noun   1      1
3 Preposition   1      1
4        Noun   0      1
5       Other   2      1
6       Other   5      0
```